# IP Address headers (Remote_Addr) - When is this header sent by the browser?

Tags: http, firefox, http-headers

I want to know when a browser includes the header - `Remote_Addr` in the HTTP request. I observed the request sent by the browser on loading `stackoverflow.com`, in the web console window of Firefox. There were no headers pertaining to IP address sent. So, does this mean the browser never sends this header along with a HTTP request?

Answer (score 14):

In client-server applications, the IP address of the client (i.e., the browser) is sent via the socket connection (the request) to the server (e.g., Apache). If the client is using a proxy server however, that may be the proxy's IP address instead of the client's IP.

`Remote_Addr` is an ENV returned by the server and available to server-side scripts/applications, not the client browser.

In PHP, you can use something like `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` to obtain the IP address of the client. In Perl you can use something like `$ENV{'REMOTE_ADDR'};`